# Transferring a file from an input to an iframe JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf, file-upload, frontend, text-extraction

I am working on a project : I need to extract the text of a PDF file and put this text in a "div".

For the moment I managed to do it by using the tag `<iframe>`.

But it works only when I know the path of the PDF File like for instance  : `src="nameofthefile.pdf" or src="folder/nameofthefile.pdf"`... And now I would like to have the same result but when this PDF file is uploaded by an extern users in front-end.

So I think about the tag `<input id="input" type="file">` but when I used it alone with my PDF I manage but the text is still encoded ...

So here are my questions (sorry for this four questions ... :P)

***0) Firstly is it easy to decode a PDF text so that I can use only the `<input>` tag ?***

***1) If not  can we get back a file in input and stock it in an iframe ? (thanks to javascript)***

***2) If the answer to the second question is "no" does it exist a way to upload a PDF file in an iframe and to give to this frame a special "src"attribute. Or is it possible to define dynamically the attribute "src" (like in day-to-day language :  "if a user uploads a PDF file, my programm is able to know that the PDF is at this precise place and so it can extract the text" ?***

***3) Or last question : is it possible to upload a file thanks to the tag `<iframe>` by using only javascript or maybe JQuery but no AJAX or PHP? If not which method I should work on it ?***

(I don't really want to use backend technologies like PHP^^)

To sum up about my code : I integrated the code from https://github.com/hubgit/hubgit.github.com/tree/master/2011/11/pdftotext into my project. But you need to know the src of the PDF ...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know if you can "extract" the text out of a PDF. But i think the part with the "special" src attribut would be the easyest way to use php.

```
<?php 
$file = //Some Code for choosing the newest file in a directory;
echo '<iframe src="',$file,'"></iframe>';
?>
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer,

yes we can extract the text thanks PHP and also thank to Javasript thanks to the library PDF.js (really useful). I managed it already but the PDF file needs to be on my computer. My aim is to have the same result but when a PDF file is uploaded. I managed to put the text from a  text file (Ex : myfile.txt) into a div. Now I hope it is also possible with a pdf file without using backend technics ;-)